# I'm new to C, what does it mean when you make a variable equal to another variable and 0.0 at the same time?

Tags: c, do-while, absolute-value

[Code provided in my lecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byvaz.png)

I'm very curious about how does the "term" variable work in the first line of code when it codes:
double pi = 0.0, term;

I also am unable to run this code on VSCode IDE
[Error Code C4578](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMyQB.png)

I can't seem to find an answer on Google, so I came here.
On the error of running the code, I tried to change numbers (adding decimal places) because it says its a data conversion problem with abs(). I think its something with abs() only outputing int datatype, is there anyway to fix it?

Thank u so much if you are seeing this, its my first time coding ;)

Comment: Please attach your entire code (include `#include`s) as text, not screenshot. And the error message too.

Comment: The errors shown are not for that, but on different lines: the first is a warning for `int places = 10.0;`. The second error is using the integer macro `abs` on a floating point value.

Comment: The `.cpp` file names indicate C++ not C.

Comment: In the future, always reduce a problem to a [mre]: Make a complete program, with a `main` routine, that reproduces the problem, and show the compiler error messages by pasting them into the question as text, not as an image.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I'm so stupid. Learn't many things from your replies tysm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `double pi = 0.0, term;`, `pi = 0.0` and `term` are separate items. Equivalent code is `double pi = 0.0;`, which defines `pi` to be a `double` and initializes it to zero, and `double term;`, which defines `term` and does not specify an initial value for it.

The error “'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data'” is from the line `int places = 10.0;`, which specifies a `double` value, `10.0`, for an `int` object, `places`. To eliminate the warning, change this to `int places = 10;`.

In `C`, `abs` is a function for the `int` type. The fact that this code uses it with a `double` operand, `term`, indicates this is C++ code, and the file name, `L2.1-2.3.cpp`, also indicates this is C++ code. You seem to have requested your compiler to compile it as C code, which is why it gives you the message “'abs': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data”. You should change whatever setting is telling your compiler to compile this as C code.

Comment: tysm man, I'm so stupid = =

Comment: It seems that the code provided in my lecture has made a small mistake, I changed abs() to fabs() and was able to get the desired outcome ty